# C# Math.Ceiling is not working like what I have read and researched. Windows Forms App

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

So this should be a quick and easy fix someone could help me with. I have made it to were I need to round a number that is going to come out as a float possibly at points just simply round up to the nearest integer. This is the code I have so far.

```
int result = ci * di;
                    double result1 = result * 0.10;
                    if (result1 == result1)
                        Math.Ceiling((double)result1);
                    if (result1 >= 1000)
                        result1 = 1000;
```

When I run the program it goes through without errors but fails to do what I want. Also if there is any way to make that code look cleaner than what it is I'm all for it. But back to topic, if I type in lets say 56 in one box and 3 in the other, it should come out to saying that I have a value of 16.8 due to the percentage calculations I have done. When I try the math.ceiling there, it doesn't round anything. Also, the greater than or equal to 1000 thing is just because I don't want that number going over 1000. Thank you for any help that anyone may offer.

Comment: `Math.Ceiling` returns a value that must be assigned.  It does not change the value of `result1`.

Comment: '(double)result1' cast is useless and it is a bad habit tp have useless cast.

Comment: Reading the documentation would reveal that `Math.Ceiling` is a **function** that returns a value, which means you have to use that returned value in order to get the results of the function call.

Comment: @FinderFake While coding in VS and encountering/using a function you're not fully familiar about, just press F1 while your cursor is on it to see the full docs & example.

You'll get an error if you use it with integer literal, like Math.Ceiling(5), since it's ambiguous between calling the double or decimal version. If you use Math.Ceiling(d) where d is a double or decimal, or with double/decimal literal like Math.Ceiling(7.0) or Math.Ceiling(7.0m), there won't be any error

Comment: @Martheen Thank you for the advice, I mainly do all of this for fun and to learn more. I didn't even know about hitting F1 when coding in VS. Thank you to everyone that helped me with this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `Math.Ceiling` does not change the value of your `double result1` it returns it. The variable `result1` must be explicitly re-assigned to the output of the `Math.Ceiling` function if you wish for it to take the output of that function. You can assign it like this.

```
result1 = Math.Ceiling(result1);
```

Comment: You can also remove the redundant cast, since `result1` is already declared `double`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard thanks, forgot to take that out.